# Why do I get a "foo: not found" error whe assigning a variable?

Tags: bash

I am getting `foo: not found` when running the following code:

```sh
foo = "`cat test.txt`"
```

contents of test.txt:

```
Hello World
```

Comment: Btw.: `\`...\`` is deprecated. Use `$(...)`.

Comment: [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) automatically detects common problems including this one

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for defining a variable is without spaces:

```
foo="`cat test.txt`"
```

Answer (score 1):

When you omit the spaces around the `=` it will work.

```sh
foo="`cat test.txt`"
```

With the space after `foo`, bash tries to run the command `foo` with `=` as first argument and `` "`cat test.txt`" `` as second argument. But since you don't have an executable in your path called `foo`, bash then complains that it can not find `foo`.